# image in the footer frame of an alert dialog

Tags: android, dialog, drawable

I would like to put an image in the footer frame of the alert dialog.
can someone please tell if it is possible, and how?
I know it is possible to create a custom dialog, is it the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this, which gives a idea to create custom alertdialog.

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/06/custom-alertdialog.html

Answer (score 0):

try to find method related to load a image in alert dialog box and then call that method with the object of AlertDialog.Builder and give image path in that...I dont know whether it will work or not but still we can try it...